# USB extension cable drops external USB disk speed

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have a (new) Seagate USB 3.0 4 TB disk here. Without extension cable I have about 100 MB/s read speed. But when I use a (quite new) Amazon Basics 2m USB extension cable it drops to 40 MB/s.

As far as I know, the extension cable is only a cable and the PC cannot know there is one. I assume many USB packets have to be repeated because of a bad checksum.

But I am not sure. Should I throw the cable away or is this normal?

The speeds were measured using `dd` on Linux and should be reliable.

Comment: Try a better cable.  I have an Apple certified 2 meter cable and it works fine. The PC may not know, but cables have physical characteristics. They are not all the same.

Comment: It seems to me you have already identified the problem, the problem is the cable.

Comment: It sounds like your extension cable is USB v2 and your device is USB v3. Are you sure your extension cable is USB v3?

Comment: @Keltari I did not know USB3 requires special cables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You are connecting a USB 3.0 device with a USB 2.0 extension cable.

You state:

> “I have a (new) Seagate USB 3.0 4 TB disk here. Without extension cable I have about 100 MB/s read speed. But when I use a (quite new) Amazon Basics 2m USB extension cable it drops to 40 MB/s.”

This is most likely an issue where you are connecting a USB 3.0 device with a USB 2.0 cable. I say this with confidence since the first hit I get in a Google search for an Amazon Basics USB extension cable is this 3m one:

- [Amazon Basics USB 2.0 Extension Cable - A-Male to A-Female Adapter Cord - 9.8 Feet (3 Meters), Black](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NH11PEY)

USB 2.0 and USB 1.x both use 4 wires to connect. But USB 3.0 more than the standard 4 USB wires to connect; thus increased speed. More details on [USB 3.0 can be found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0).

These cables typically clearly state they are USB 3.0 cables and the connectors on each end has blue colored plastic in the connector itself. Here is a close up of the “A” end of such a cable from that previously mentioned Wikipedia article on USB 3.0.

[image]

Here is another Amazon Basics extension cable that is clearly marked as USB 3.0.

- [Amazon Basics USB 3.0 Extension Cable - A-Male to A-Female Extender Cord - 6 Feet (2 Pack)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014RWATK2)

> “Should I throw the cable away or is this normal?”

Well, you can throw out the USB 2.0 extension cable if you wish. But if you want USB 3.0 speeds you need a USB 3.0 extension cable.

FWIW, any USB 3.0 extension cable is backwards compatible with USB 2.0, but a USB 2.0 extension cable will “work” but will never give you USB 3.0 speeds.

PS: You also state this.

> “I assume many USB packets have to be repeated because of a bad checksum.”

None of this has to do with bad checksums. You are not dealing with some deep technical issue here; checksums are not a factor in a case like this. This is simply a case where the drive cannot connect as a USB 3.0 device if the extension cable is USB 2.0.

Comment: Oh I always thought the additional pins were only used for connecting screens or so. Thank you for opening my eyes.